# Is direct advertisement allowed on mobile android app?

Tags: software, terms-of-service, advertisements, google

Suppose that an app developer D wants to advertise on a mobile android app. D is aware that that there is the ad network platform admob provided by google, but D does not want to use it.

D wants  to carry ads on D's mobile app from various businesses by directly contacting them (bypassing google/admob).

Is this OK to display ads in a mobile app by directly getting ads from advertisers? Would doing so violate any Google policy? Will D's mobile app be banned if D does this?

Comment: Banned by whom If? And if you've no connection with or using Google, why would you violate their policy?

Comment: Banned by google play store

Comment: Google is a private business; they can ban anyone from the play store, as per their TOS.

Comment: This is a pretty simple legal matter: read the TOS and see if the action is prohibited. Are you asking us to read and interpret the Playstore TOS for you? Or are you planning on distributing the app some other way, bypassing Playstore? In the latter case, Google probably gets no say.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it calls for speculation as to a company's enforcement of its policy, rather than asking a question about the law.

Answer (score 2):

The Play Store has an [advertising policy](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9857753?hl=en&ref_topic=9857752#1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9) regarding this. It does not mandate the use of admob, so developers are free to seek and implement advertisements themselves.

It does, however, limit the content and implementation of ads, which you agree to as the ToS of the Play Store. These include not being for inappropriate content, not being misleading, not being disruptive etc.